# Prim's Algorithm through adjacency matrix

Tags: algorithm, prims-algorithm

I am thinking of using Prim's algorithm for optimizing a water pipeline problem. I am very much puzzled how to initialize the adjacency matrix when there is an edge with adjacent vertex found. I thought of putting weight whenever an edge exists. However, w(Vi,Vj) in itself looks to be a weight matrix. So, why do I need A{Vi,Vj} in the first place.

All i intent to do is to write an algorithmic approach, and carry on with writing a program later on. Please suggest if below is ok?

1. Set an adjacency matrix A{Vi,Vj}. Here Vi contains all the nodes visited and Vj contains all the adjacent nodes to Vi that are visited. Below matrix will store all the pair of houses which are connected with their neighbouring pair of houses through a certain distance. I am confused tha

   **for** each Vi:=1 to n do      //Vith is the ith vertex which stores a pair of house
        **for** each Vj:=1 to n  do    //Vjth is the adjacent pair of house with some weight
           **if** (edge exists between Vi and Vj) then
               **Set** A{Vi,Vj} with w(Vi,Vj)
           **else if**(edge not exists between Vi and Vj) then
               **Set** A[Vi,Vj]:=0
2. Calculating the minimum spanning tree.
3. Output: Displaying the total water-pipeline required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In graph algorithms as in your question, if weights are given, usually adjacency is not explicitly encoded in addition to the weights. Instead, the graph is considered to be a complete graph (i.e. evey vertex is adjacent to any other vertex), but for non-adjacent vertices `u`, `v` in the initial graph the weight is encoded as 'infinity', encoded as the maximum value of the used data type, some negative value which is recognized in calculations or the like. Using this approach, infeasible edges will never be taken into accout as they are more expensive than any feasible solution of the initial problem.

Comment: Ok so u are saying I can assume that if edge exists the matrix will contain weight, and will it will not it will be infinity?

Comment: Yes, exactly, each non-existent edge is supposed to have infinite weight; additionally, some arithmetic convention is used that a value is infinity as soon as any of its summands or factors is infinity. This will yield an answer of finite value if the input has a solution (in this case the value is the optimal value), otherwise the output will be of infinite value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, using the adjacency matrix is a feasible method to implement the Prim's algorithm to build minimum spanning tree. And the running time is O(V^2). To be more specific, you will have a nested for loop, the outer loop costs O(V), which is each time it picks up the vertex with the min cost adding to the MST. So for this, you will have to make a key array, key[v],to keep the cost of vertex adding to tree. And also an array mst[v] to make sure after each iteration, a vertex should be visited

   2. Then the inner for loop, based on the prim's algorithm, each time after picking up the vertex,v, with minimum cost key[v],adding to the current mst, what should you do next before mark the mst[v] as visited? You should use the "adjacency matrix" to compare/update the cost of v's neighbor adding to the mst. This is important, so whenever it chooses a vertex and add it to the tree, Prim's will update the vertex's cost of adding to mst via the information it gets from v. So next time it picks up the u again with min cost, and it just repeats again until all vertices are discovered, mst[v] will be all true. Therefore, in the inner for loop, it uses the row representing the v and examines all neighbors of v, which are all columns in the row. If, say the w[i][j], is less than the current adding cost of vertex j, key[j]. Then use the weight of v to that vertex to be the adding cost of that vertex, key[j] = w[i][j]. And after all of the v's neighbors have been visited, then mark v as finished.
   3. So the prim's is clear, it's better to set the "non - existing" edges to be weight of 0, so in the matrix, w[i][j] = 0 , which means vertex i and vertex j are not reachable from each other, and each time you pick up a v and should examine it's neighbor, it only looks at positive value. Also, the diagonal of the matrix should be set to all zeros, because when there is reason to figure out the cost of adding a vertex that's already in the mst to mst. In conclusion, if each time prim's examines the neighbors of v, w[i][j] < key[j], the current adding cost, then key[j] = w[i][j].
   4. the running time of this algorithm, *O(V)* to set all array initialization, set key[root] = 0, and other vertices, key[v] = inf, infinity adding cost to mst, and mst[v] as null.
      Then *O(V)* for the outer loop iteration, then within the outer loop, to pick up a vertex, v, with min cost each time, so it costs O(V), it could be better using min-heap. And then examine all neighbors of v. it will be O(E) including all the examinations. So the iterations cost : O(V)*(V) + O(E), and the prim's algorithm cost can be bounded up by O(V^2)